# Loop over .csv file containing paths and add labels to second column

Tags: python, csv, google-api, google-vision

Currently I am trying out google vision. I have gathered a fair collection of images which I now want to label using google vision.

So far I have a .csv file, where the first column consists of the paths to the images. Now I am trying to loop over the paths and then add the corresponding labels to the second column.

```
import os
import io
from google.cloud import vision
import csv
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud.vision import types


os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Test1\ServiceAccountToken.json'
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

csvPath = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Test1\pictures\Tests.csv'


with io.open(csvPath, 'rb') as csv_file:
    for lines in csv_file:
        with io.open(lines, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
            image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
            response = client.label_detection(image=image)
            labels = response.label_annotations.description
```

So after running this code I would like to have this .csv file that contains the labels in the second columns at the moment I also get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test1/googleVisionTests.py", line 17, in <module>
    with io.open(lines, 'r') as image_file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: b'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test1/pictures/35mm-tR-hmR1ZGmE-unsplash.jpg\r\n'
```

I hope somebody can help out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
with io.open(csvPath, 'rb') as csv_file:
```

with

```
with io.open(csvPath, 'r') as csv_file:
```

'rb' opens file in binary mode which is not required here for csv file